# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\appends()

Tags: laravel

i want to using appends in pagination, but error like this

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\appends()
```

.
this is my controller ...

```
  public function index(InstrumentType $instrumentType)
{ 
    $query = "";

    if(request('serial_number')){
        $query = request('serial_number');
    }

    $instruments =  Instrument::where('instrument_type_id', $instrumentType->id)->where('serial_number', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->paginate(5);
    $instruments = appends($request->query());
    return view('settinginstrument.index', compact('instrumentType', 'instruments'));
}
```

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$instruments->appends($request->query());
```

Instead of

```
appends($request->query());
```

try this:

```
public function index(Request $request, InstrumentType $instrumentType)
{ 
    $query = "";

    if(request('serial_number')){
        $query = request('serial_number');
    }

    $instruments =  Instrument::where('instrument_type_id', $instrumentType->id)->where('serial_number', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->paginate(5);
    $instruments = $instruments->appends($request->query());
    return view('settinginstrument.index', compact('instrumentType', 'instruments'));
}
```

For more information check this : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

Comment: Updated, defined `Request $request` in your index function parameter and make sure included with `use` at the top of controller

Comment: By convention, request should be the first argument: `public function index(Request $request, InstrumentType $instrumentType)`.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter is there any issue, if request is second argument

Comment: Yes, for instance, if parameters are not type hinted. Or if for whatever reason `func_get_args()` is used. Just a couple cases, I'm sure there are more.